# Can Reinforcement Learning be used for UAV waypoint control?

Tags: flight-controller, software, firmware, long-range-drone

I want to make a drone which can follow static and dynamic waypoints. I am a total beginner in the drone field so I can't figure out whether I should use Reinforcement Learning or other learning methods for the drone to make it follow both static and dynamic waypoints. If RL is the best choice for the task, then how would I go about training the model before uploading it to the flight controller. And if RL is not required, then what should I use in order to achieve this task?

Currently, I have no clue about which software to use for the task. I am very interested in this field and I would love to learn more. Please let me know how I should begin with this task.

Comment: Hi Ravish, welcome to Drones.SE! As you've currently phrased your question, it encompasses multiple distinct topics, which isn't a great fit for our Q&A model. Please narrow the scope of your question and/or break it up into multiple separate question threads.

Comment: I have made the edits that make it directed on the 'waypoints' problem only. I really need help to get started with this. Do let me know if more changes are required, thanks.\

Comment: The body text of your question is, unfortunately, missing details. As I read it it isn't clear to me whether you're asking for ground simulation or real-time controller software recommendations.

Comment: The question body also contains remnants from your previous title asking about recommendations for a flight controller. Maybe this ask would be more clear if you provide some more information about what you're trying to build?

Comment: We have to make an autonomous UAV, so I think a real time controller software would be needed. As we cannot risk damaging the parts, we would like to use a simulation software for checking if the RL model is giving desired results or not before actually testing it. I just need to know whether RL is the best choice for the waypoints task or not. If it is, how should I go about implementing it? And if its not, how should I proceed then?

Comment: Oh, so then your question is *Can Reinforcement Learning be used for UAV waypoint control?*, right?

Comment: Yes, and what software to use in order to implement it. Thanks, I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Ah, understood. You've got yourself a question, my friend! Unfortunately, I have no experience in this area, so I won't be of much use to you for answers. :( Best of luck!

Comment: No problem, and thankss!

Comment: There is also an artificial intelligence stack exchange site, which answers questions about reinforcement learning. But you might get an answer here. Let's see!

Answer (score 3):

Reinforcement Learning can be used for UAV control. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0A9voXzhng) details a method to use RL for quadcopters.

In summary, you program a model of your UAV that effectively simulates your drone.
You then create a policy and value neural network to control your drone and train it using your simulation.

I'm pretty sure similar methods are used in [zipline's](https://flyzipline.com/how-it-works/) autonomous drone delivery network that manages 65% of the entire country of Rwanda's blood deliveries.